# SELECT multiple rows with WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-match-all

```
PID       VALUE
3        1
4        3
1        9
1        3
```

How to select row(s) that has **both** values 3 and 9? I tried

> select PID from table where VALUE = 3 and VALUE = 9

So that i get something like below, instead i get an empty set.

```
PID      
1
```

PID 4 should not be included in the result because it do not have VALUE 9

Comment: Wow people really don't read these questions for actual meaning do they? I'd use a `group by PID`, a `where value in (3, 9)`, and a `having count(*) = 2`.

Comment: Amazing how many people don't know what "both" means. Though, to be fair, the OP's use of the word "row" is misleading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WHERE clause can only evaluate conditions against *one* row from a given table at a time.  You can't make a condition span multiple rows.

But you can use a *self-join* to match multiple rows from the same table into one row of the result set, so you can apply a condition that involves both.

```
SELECT t1.pid
FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.pid=t2.pid
WHERE t1.value = 3 AND t2.value = 9;
```

An alternative solution is to use GROUP BY and count the *distinct* values:

```
SELECT t.pid
FROM table t
WHERE t.value IN (3,9)
GROUP BY t.pid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.value) = 2;
```

Comment: good answer - not enough detailin question but answer will change if bigger amount of data in tables

Comment: I'd say to go with the GROUP BY method, since there's no guarantee of join order for the first; i.e., t1.value may be 9 and t2.value may be 3.

Comment: @Paul Sonier: The WHERE clause makes sure t1 *does* match the rows where value is 3, and t2 *does* match the rows where value is 9.  That is, it examines all rows until it finds those that match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

This, I think is a little more along the lines of what you're after:

```
select PID from table
where VALUE IN (3, 9) 
group by PID
having count(*) = 2
```

Basically this looks for entries that have either a 3 or a 9, groups them together, and returns only the ones that have a count of two. I'm assuming here (perhaps incorrectly) that there can *only* be one 3 and one 9 per PID.

Comment: Right, that's usually not a safe assumption. If two rows both have value 9, COUNT(*) will return 2, even though no row exists with value 3.

Comment: Fair enough, still it should give the OP a general direction. I'd correct it using DISTINCT but that solution has already been proposed so I'll just keep this as is.

Comment: Yep, it depends on the table.  If there's a UNIQUE constraint over (pid,value) then your solution would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As well as 'group by' you could also consider 'select distinct' to return a unique set of pids.